# File with input/output error on SSD

Tags: ssd

My laptop generally works fine. However I have, as far as I can tell, a single file that gives me an input/output error when I try to copy it:

```
$ cp badfile badfile.copy
cp: error reading 'badfile': Input/output error
```

In /var/log/syslog I see this:

> blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector
> 468307904 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0

My SSD is less than a year old, so if it's failing I can get a replacement. The thing is, I bought the laptop without an operating system, so I need to be able to prove that it's a hardware problem. How can I do that?

I've tried doing a filesystem check on the disk from a bootable USB, and it couldn't find anything wrong with it. smartctl doesn't look wrong, but my eye is untrained: what should I be looking for?

Comment: I read the syslog as hard drive fail but hey that is just me.